React Native horizontal and vertical scroll
I have a header component and 3 tabs, the contents inside the tabs are dynamic, I want to scroll horizontally between the tabs and also if a tab has large content it should scroll along with the header.
I have tried
import React from 'react';
import { ScrollView, View, Text, Dimensions, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';

const { width } = Dimensions.get('window');

const ScrollViewContainer = () => {
  return (
    
<SafeAreaView>
<ScrollView >
    <View style={{ padding: 20 }}>
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 20 }}>Username</Text>
        <Text>Description</Text>
      </View>


    <ScrollView
      horizontal={true}
      pagingEnabled={true}
      showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
      
    >

         <View style={{ width }}>
        <ScrollView >
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 30 }}>Large content for Page 1</Text>
          {/* More content */}
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
      <View style={{ width }}>
        <ScrollView >
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 30 }}>Large content for Page 2</Text>
              <Text style={{ fontSize: 30 }}>to play with the API but don't feel like trying it on a real app, you can run the example project. Check Example/ directory README for installation instructions.
        to play with the API but don't feel like trying it on a real app, you can run the example project. Check Example/ directory README for installation instructions.
        to play with the API but don't feel like trying it on a real app, you can run the example project. Check Example/ directory README for installation instructions.
        to play with the API but don't feel like trying it on a real app, you can run the example project. Check Example/ directory README for installation instructions.
        to play with the API but don't feel like trying it on a real app, you can run the example project. Check Example/ directory README for installation instructions.

         to play with the API but don't feel like trying it on a real app, you can run the example project. Check Example/ directory README for installation instructions.
          to play with the API but don't feel like trying it on a real app, you can run the example project. Check Example/ directory README for installation instructions.
        </Text>
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
      <View style={{ width }}>
        <ScrollView nestedScrollEnabled>
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 30 }}>Large content for Page 23</Text>
          {/* More content */}
        </ScrollView>
      </View>

    </ScrollView>
    </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default ScrollViewContainer;

but this is not allowing the inner scrollViews to scroll
I can't pre define the height but I can calculate it by multiplying each cards height
Think of this similar to instagram profile page

i think you need Top Tabs Navigator
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/material-top-tab-navigator/

nice one I think this library is useful
